# How to create a Time Series Training Dataset with variable sequence length

Tags: python, time-series, dataset, training

I have time series data with variable sequence lengths.
So something like:

```
date        value label
2020-01-01  2     0     # first input time series
2020-01-02  1     0     # first input time series
2020-01-03  1     0     # first input time series
2020-01-01  3     1     # second input time series
2020-01-03  1     1     # second input time series
```

how is it possible to create a training dataset (numpy arrays) of shape `[samples, time_steps, n_features]` when `time_steps` is not consistent?

Additional Info: The model that is going to be trained is an `LSTM` which is capable to handle variable input lengths.

Comment: What would be the needed dataset in your example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it the following way:

1. zero padding all time series that are smaller than the longest one
2. adding a `Masking()`layer with `masking_value=0.` which ignores all zero values before feeding the network.

The part of the model with the Masking layer looks like the following:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Masking(mask_value=0., input_shape=(None, 1)))
model.add(layers.LSTM(100))
```

Additional Info: Implementing the Masking Layer for a Model with two separate Inputs was kind of unconvinient with a the `Keras Functional API`, therefore i implemented that part of the model with the `Keras Sequential API` and connected it to the rest of the model which is implemented with the Functional API.